# Number of orbits of a subgroup of the symmetric group $S_9$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, abstract-algebra

> Let $H=\langle (3\quad 4\quad 5),(1\quad 2\quad3)(7\quad8\quad9)\rangle \le S_9$ be a subgroup in $S_9$. Find number of orbits and their order.

First I noticed $\mathrm{orb}(6)=\{6\}$. I also think that $\mathrm{orb}(3)=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ but I can't explain how (and if so, then also $\mathrm{orb}(7)=\{7,8,9\}$). Another problem is I don't know to explain myself why a permutation send one of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ to $\{7,8,9\}$ does not exist. How can I explain both problems?

Comment: Have you listed down all the elements in $H$?

Comment: Prahlad, yes.@PraphullaKoushik I meant this orbit: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbit_%28group_theory%29#Orbits_and_stabilizers

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I think that my edit sorted that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but rather a hint on what you need to understand.
I assume (though you should specify) that the set upon which your $S_9$ is acting is $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$. If this is the case, then the permutation $\sigma=(3,4,5)$ takes $3$ to $4$, takes $4$ to $5$, takes $5$ to $3$, and leaves $1,2,6,7,8,9$ fixed. In the same manner you can see what the permutation $\tau=(1,2,3)(7,8,9)$ does to each element of the set $\{1,\dots,9\}$. In order to compute the orbits of this group action you need also to consider composing the two permutations that generate your subgroup, for example, $(\tau\circ\sigma)(5)=1$. Methods for doing that involve [Burnside's lemma and the orbit-stabilizer theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbit_%28group_theory%29#Orbit-stabilizer_theorem_and_Burnside.27s_lemma).

Comment: so as follows I can just write the composition of $\sigma\circ\dots\circ\tau\dots\tau$ never takes a numbef from 1..5 to 7..9?

Comment: @CoarguAliquis There different orders in which you can compose permutations (composition of permutations is not commutative!), but eventually there is no permutation in your subgroup that takes an element of $\{1,\dots,5\}$ to an element of $\{7,8,9\}$.